# "時のように" versus "ように"

Tags: adverbs

> 佐々：「それなら、もう一つお前に聞くが、お前の願いを聞いてやったら、お前たちはすぐに殺される。父の顔を見ることはできないが、それでもいいか。」
>
> いち：「それで、結構でございます。」
>
> いちは、冷たく静かに答えたが、何か心に浮かんだらしく、すぐその後に
>
> いち：「『お上』のなさることに間違いはございませんでしょうから。」
>
> 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられた**時のように**、驚いた顔をした。

This sentence sparks my curiosity that why the author inserted "時" before "よう".

Could the author simply put it as

> 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられた**ように**、驚いた顔をした。

If not, what is the difference between the two sentence?

(I forgot to put 顔をした in the first edition, sorry.)

Comment: I add more context to make the scenario more clear and well-described.

Comment: I would like to thank all of you sharing your explanation and opinions. All of three say "時のように" can imply there is a similar event happened in the past. In this case, however, it doesn't have this meaning, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question! Both sentences mean "Sasa was surprised as if she got splashed suddenly." and there are little differences. However, the former one is sometimes interpreted in following two meanings:
[1] Sasa was surprised as if she got splashed suddenly.(Same as to the latter)
[2] Sasa was surprised like a time when she got splashed suddenly.(actualy happened in the past)

Answer (score 1):

I personally don’t find semantic difference in your example though,

> 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられた時のように、驚いた。

Probably this author might have an experience of soaking cold water or actually observed Sasa was being soaked with cold water.

Sasa was surprised like when you were showered cold water suddenly.

> 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられたかのように、驚いた。

This sentence implies the author haven’t never seen Sasa was being soaked with cold water though, the author describes that “Sasa was surprised as if being soaked by cold water.”

高校生の(時の)ように野球をする。

I play base ball when I was a high school student.(with 時の)

I play base ball as if I were a high school student.( without 時の)

Answer (score 1):

> (A) 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられた**時のように**、驚いた。
>   (B) 佐々は突然冷たい水を浴びせられた**ように**、驚いた。

(A) means (C).

> (C) 佐々は過去に突然冷たい水を浴びせられて驚いた（ことがある）。今回佐々はそのように/その時のようにおどろいた。
>   *(There was a fact that) Sasa was surprised when she suddenly got splashed with cold water in the past. Sasa was surprised like that this time.*

My attempt for (B) is as follows.

> Sasa was surprised as if she suddenly got splashed with cold water.